# retrieving all rows from table (PostgreSQL) using Hibernate output corrupted

Tags: java, database, postgresql, hibernate

So I'm new to hibernate and I want make a method which will retrieve everything in table "servers". There are three columns: serverId, server_name and server_Ip. I can successfully add and remove rows from my table via hibernate but when I'm trying to get all of them then output looks like the List isn't casted on my mapped class (ServerEntity). I'm really stuck on this probably trivial issue.

This is method for retrieving rows from table servers

```
 public static  List<ServersEntity[]>  readDB() {
     final Session session = getSession();
     session.getSessionFactory().openSession();
     session.beginTransaction();

     String hql = "FROM ServersEntity";
     Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
     List results = query.list();
     session.getTransaction().commit();

     System.out.println(results);
     session.close();
     return results;
}
```

this is output of this method via System.out.print(list)

```
[org.openjfx.ServersEntity@e9113e0a, org.openjfx.ServersEntity@ae36623e, org.openjfx.ServersEntity@ae36661f, org.openjfx.ServersEntity@ae8cd466]
```

ServersEntity.class

```
package org.openjfx;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "servers", schema = "public", catalog = "SERVERS")
public class ServersEntity {
    private int serverId;
    private String serverName;
    private String serverIp;

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "idgen", strategy = "increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "idgen")
    @Column(name = "server_ID", nullable = false)
    public int getServerId() {
        return serverId;
    }

    public void setServerId(int serverId) {
        this.serverId = serverId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "server_name", nullable = true, length = -1)
    public String getServerName() {
        return serverName;
    }

    public void setServerName(String serverName) {
        this.serverName = serverName;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "server_IP", nullable = true, length = -1)
    public String getServerIp() {
        return serverIp;
    }

    public void setServerIp(String serverIp) {
        this.serverIp = serverIp;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        ServersEntity that = (ServersEntity) o;
        return serverId == that.serverId &&
                Objects.equals(serverName, that.serverName) &&
                Objects.equals(serverIp, that.serverIp);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(serverId, serverName, serverIp);
    }
}
```

Comment: All the objects inside the list are instances of ServersEntity. So what is the concrete problem? What are you doing, what do you expect to happen, and what happens, precisely?

Comment: OK, I guess the problem is with your return type. The list is a list of ServersEntity. It's not a List of arrays of ServersEntity. And I don't see why you would want a list of arrays of ServersEntity. So change the return type to List<ServersEntity>, instead of List<ServersEntity[]>.

Comment: I'm really dumb I don't have any idea now how do I get objects which I've put them instead instances of them. Database isn't empty https://i.imgur.com/MzeNe37.png Something like initializing an Array of my class?

Comment: Ok when I added "SELECT server_name FROM ServerEntity" it works as it is supposed to do https://i.imgur.com/xVEtpQ3.png but when I add server_Ip it display instances

Answer (score 1):

I think that your code is OK. You recive List of `ServersEntity`. And `System.out.println` print this list. Problem is `System.out.println` don't "know" how print your `ServersEntity` and print class-name and id of object. Try add `toString` method in your ServersEntity class:

```
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return serverName + ": " + serverIp;
  }
```

and run your code.

When you try `SELECT server_name FROM ServerEntity` your recieve List of strings. And `System.out.println` "know" how to print it.

Comment: OMG IT WAS THAT SIMPLE. Thank you very much :3